# Update thread parameter

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How to update thread parameter?

```
string str = "hello world"; 

private static Thread test = newThread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(invariant_loop));

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Start(str);
}

private static void invariant_loop(object value)
{
    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
    while (true);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    str = maskedTextBox1.Text; // update value ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `String` is immutable data structure you can not doing such kind of operations (passing parameters). Use an other reference type or wrap string by a class with appropriate methods which able to modify underlying string field:

```
class TextWrapper
{   
   public string TextValue 
   { 
       get; 
       set; 
   }  
}
```

Define TextWrapper field on the level where you've defined `str`, then instantiate and pass instance of TextWrapper to a thread.

**See very good article by Yoda**: [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to previous answer this should accomplish the same without passing a variable.
Just make sure the shared variable is locked to avoid race conditions.

```
string str = "hello world"; 
object str_lock = new object();

private Thread test = newThread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(invariant_loop));

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test.Start();
}

private void invariant_loop()
{
    do
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        lock(str_lock) {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock(str_lock) {
        str = maskedTextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```